# how to stretch/resize svgs in uwp's xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, svg, uwp

Since the creators update came out, uwp can use svg images as briefly explained [here (minute 3)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Windows-Developer-Day-Creators-Update/Building-personal-and-productive-apps-with-Composition-and-XAML-updates).

I have [this svg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Desktop/master/images/double-check.svg) (48x48) and i can use it fine, if (and only if) i set the image's width&height to 48 and the strech to none:

`<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets//check.svg" Height="48" Width="48" Stretch="None"/>`

If i set the stretch to fill, the image disappears. If i increase the width and height i can see that the icon is pinned to the upper left corner of the image ([screenshot with a different svg but same size](https://s10.postimg.org/j5k91825l/svg.png)). Isn't Stretch=Fill and a fixed height/width the intended way to scale an image?

It looks to my as if the stretching algorithm does not grasp that my svg is supposed to be 48x48. Am i doing it wrong, or are there workarounds?

Comment: I thought Image.Source required [BitmapImage class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) so I would assume it's rendering that SVG as a raster bitmap. Which means you'll likely need to either wrap the `Image` in a [ViewBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox) or personally I would just use XAML Path Markup which is similar to SVG and you can export to that format from Adobe Illustrator. I hadn't heard of the SVG support and it's not even in the docs yet but that would be cool if it got supported fully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been having the same issue all morning and was about to completely give up on Svg support, seems mad that you can't get a scalable format to scale properly...

But, I had one more go and I think I've worked this out.

It seems that you need to tell the `SvgImageSource` to rasterize at the SVG's original design size and then get the `Image` to scale it. Not sure it's a particularly helpful approach, but certainly solves it as of build 15063.

```
<Image Width="24" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Image.Source>
    <SvgImageSource UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/salesorder.folder.plain.svg"
                    RasterizePixelHeight="48"
                    RasterizePixelWidth="48" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

So if the SVG was 48x48 we turn it into a bitmap at 48x48 using the `RasterizePixelHeight` and `RasterizePixelWidth` values and then the image scales that to 24x24.

Hope that helps.

**Update**
I just re-read your question and realised that you were looking to increase the scale whereas I've been working to decrease it. Looks as though the technique still works, but as you scale up you're going to lose any sharpness of image due to the bitmap scale process. I think this points to a fundamental flaw in the current implementation. They seem to be rendering the svg as a bitmap, and we have to tell it the original size to get it to render properly, and then they allow the bitmap code to do the rest of the work.

I think it's somewhat debateable whether this is true support or an odd half way house. Somewhere someone suggested that Adobe Illustrator can generate XAML paths, I think I'm going to look at that to see whether I can get a better quality output, shame though because I really like Inkscape :-(

Comment: This is pure gold

Comment: What's interesting is if you _don't_ set the RasterizePixelWidth/Height and rely on your Image Width/Height then your image will resize when the DPI of the display changes.
When working with SVG's you should always define the RasterizePixelWidth/Height to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 18):

Okay, so here is how I solved this!

[YouTube Video for this!](https://youtu.be/_VVtMZfrhkE)

1. Open the SVG file
2. The SVG file Width and Height - set these to auto!

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio SVG file]

Answer (score 8):

For me, it worked with modifying SVG file like this:

1. Add appropriate `preserveAspectRatio` property to `svg` tag. For me it was `"xMinYMin meet"`.
2. Set `viewbox` property of `svg` tag to this template "0 0 ActualHeight ActualWidth", in my case it was `"0 0 1050 805"`.
3. Set `height` and `width` of `svg` tag to `"auto"`.
   Now svg element is relative to `Height`, `Width` and `Stretch` properties you provide in your XAML page or view.
4. It might be needed to rebuild the project for XAML Designer to take effect.

SVG File:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1050 805" width="auto" height="auto" ... > ... </svg>
```

XAML File:

```
<Image
    Width="200"
    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Photos/Illustrations/sample.svg"
    Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Comment: Turns out for me I only needed to use `viewBox` property. I set it to values from svg image (changed `<svg height="45" width"45">` to `<svg viewBox="0 0 45 45">)`

Comment: That is honestly better than the approved answer. If you have 200% scale and the SVG image shows up a fraction of the size it needs to be, RasterizePixelHeight will convert the small image to bitmap and THEN expand it, which decreases quality.

Comment: Using `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" width="auto" height="auto"` while keeping the original viewbox was enough to allow the SVG to properly scale to fill my Image element with proper rasterization for whatever DPI the display is at.

Answer (score 2):

For me it works only if you set `RasterizePixelHeight` and `RasterizePixelWidth` to the svg original resolution (e.g. document properties in Inkscape).

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked without setting those Properties, but adding `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"` to the `<svg ...>` tag and deleting `width` and `height` from the `<svg ...>` tag.