# Image with SVG file in UWP doesn't render correctly

Tags: c#, .net, svg, uwp, rendering

I've tried to load some SVG files with the same result: they're rendering clipped and they seem to ignore the layout.

For instance:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SuppaFlight.UWP.AnglesControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="1000">

    <Image Source="Assets/treeicon.svg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />            

</UserControl>
```

Renders like this, ignoring the `Stretch` setting:

[image]

What's going on there? Is it a known problem? How to workaround this?

Comment: you can use this trick to solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/44216273/713789

Comment: If you can modify the SVG file, the third answer on that above link works best for me (modifying the SVG for auto-scaling in XAML)

Answer (score 1):

- Open the svg image in the editor
- delete the width and height properties.
- add viewbox="0 0 15 15". 15 is the value of the deleted width and height.
- add width and height properties to image tag in xaml as desired.

these steps solved my issue, may be will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your SVG image into PNG or some other format online
[Website to Convert SVG to PNG](https://convertio.co/svg-png/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32521966)