# XAML changing the source path of an svg

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to implement an application that requests weather data from OWM (OpenWeatherMap) and displays the  temperature as well as an weather icon fitting the weather outside. OWM provides icon ids for the fitting icon. You can then access those icons over a specific web path. Displaying those icons in my app worked well. Because the icons provided by OWM have got a low resolution I decided to use vector graphics, that I saved in the application directory. Displaying those vector graphics directly using this code

```
<Image Source="Assets/WeatherIcons/01d.svg" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

works just fine. But I want to adjust the used source depending on the, by OWM provided, icon id.
My Code at the moment looks like this:
MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="starting.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:starting"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="Black"
          PointerPressed="WakeUp">

        <StackPanel x:Name="WeatherInformation"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">

            <Image x:Name="WeatherIcon"
                   Height="300"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

            <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                       TextAlignment="Center">

                <Run x:Name="Temperature" FontSize="90"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run x:Name="WeatherDescription" FontSize="50"/>

            </TextBlock>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace starting
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private DispatcherTimer modeTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            updateWeather(this, this);

            modeTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(Sleep);
            modeTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

            DispatcherTimer updateWeatherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            updateWeatherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(updateWeather);
            updateWeatherTimer.Interval= new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
            updateWeatherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void updateWeather(object sender, object e)
        {
            WeatherApp.WeatherAPI myWeatherApi = new WeatherApp.WeatherAPI("Friedrichshafen,de");
            OpenWeatherMapType.WeatherStream data = myWeatherApi.GetForecast();
            WeatherIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WeatherIcons/" + data.Weather[0].Icon + ".svg"));
            Temperature.Text = Math.Round(data.Main.Temp).ToString() + "°C";
            WeatherDescription.Text = data.Weather[0].Description;
        }

        private void Sleep(object sender, object e)
        {
            StandByTime.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ActiveTime.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WeatherInformation.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            modeTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void WakeUp(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StandByTime.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ActiveTime.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            WeatherInformation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            modeTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the application there is no sign of an weather icon showing up. How's that possible?

Comment: This link may be of interest to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304896/how-to-stretch-resize-svgs-in-uwps-xaml/44216273#44216273

Comment: Also, did you test with a different file format to make sure that the issue isn't elsewhere? i.e. `"ms-appx:///Assets/WeatherIcons/" + data.Weather[0].Icon + ".png"`

Comment: I've tested it with .png files and it didn't work either. But it worked with paths refering to the according oline adresses of OWM.

Comment: And like I mentioned above, hard coding the source path in the xaml file works just fine. The height of the picture doesn't seem to matter. It makes no difference if I leave it out.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be working fine like this:
MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Image Height="300">
            <Image.Source>
                <SvgImageSource x:Name="WeatherIconSource"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void updateWeather(object sender, object e)
{
    WeatherApp.WeatherAPI myWeatherApi = new WeatherApp.WeatherAPI("Friedrichshafen,de");
    OpenWeatherMapType.WeatherStream data = myWeatherApi.GetForecast();
    WeatherIconSource.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WeatherIcons/" + data.Weather[0].Icon + ".svg");
}
```